# Dispute over interpretation of "Less smaller"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, comparatives

I know that the correct form of "less smaller" is "less small" but that is the original phrase we went to a dispute over. This is the exact phrase.

> **Someone:** Most of the sites I post on are much less smaller than AU: stackexchange.com/users/… (apart from SO ofc)
>
> **Me:** Less smaller meaning bigger? That doesn't sound right!
>
> **Someone:** Um... what site is bigger (apart from SO)?
>
> **Me:** You said less smaller meaning that everything else except SO is bigger. That is the opposite of what you were trying to say wasn't it. If you are talking about users, Superuser? https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic
>
> **Someone:** I am so lost here. I mean every site I participate on is smaller than AU (apart from SO which is much bigger)
>
> **Me:** Less small makes it opposite of smaller. Less small means bigger. The more less small something is, the bigger it is. However, that is wrong grammar anyway. Sorry for sounding nerdy. If you simply said smaller, it would have the right meaning.
>
> **Someone:** It depends on how you interpret it. I interpreted that the less small refers to much
>
> **Me:**  Less takes something to the negative (-) side of it. Small is already a negative thing. So double negative is positive.
>
> **Someone:** I disagree, I think we've just interpreted it differently.

So my question is, what is the correct interpretation of "less small" and "more small".
My personal opinion is "less small" = bigger and "more small" = smaller.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: When talking about something that is small, I would say "even smaller", not "more small". But if you were talking about something that is big, then neither seems relevant.

Comment: "**Less** and **more** smaller" is a basic grammatical error. The comparative is formed by adding "-er" to one syllable adjectives and by qualifying adjectives of two or more syllables with **more** or **less**: *It is small - it is smaller*; *He is intelligent - he is more intelligent*. ++ *"**Less** and **more** smaller"* is a tautology and thus wrong. ++ You are trying to be emphatic about the size and, as Weather Vane says, you need to say "**even** smaller" (and **even** more/less intelligent.)

Comment: 'Less smaller' involves tautology, and though tautologies are not incorrect per se (eg 'neat and tidy'), this one is unacceptable. The only arguably acceptable usage is as litotes, and this would be unusual and quirky / used for comic effect: "A is small, C is smaller; B is ... less smaller." [ie of intermediate size]. Note that a base referent (A) as well as the compared elements C and  B must be mentioned. The example here is just wrong.

Comment: It ain't worth arguing over.

Comment: Reading this post, I feel as though I have fallen down the rabbit hole with Alice.

Comment: @Greybeard I know that. I simply stated what the other person put.

Comment: @RobJarvis I felt the same way when he started to explain his opinion.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree. But I wanted to know how an unbiased, educated third party would interpret it. That was in an SE chat and not everyone in SE are native speakers. So most people are not perfect with grammar. The important thing is correct communication